# Error pulling file from SFTP using SSIS (execute package)

Tags: python, ssis

I have recevied the below error when executed through SQL server Agent

> Executed as user: **/**. Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "E:/file//import_file_.py", line 18, in       with
> pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername,
> password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "
> C:\Users\tt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pysftp_*init*_.py",
> line 140, in **init**      self.*start_transport(host, port)    File "
> C:\Users\tt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pysftp_*init**.py",
> line 176, in _start_transport      self.*transport =
> paramiko.Transport((host, port))
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File
> "C:\Users\tt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py",
> line 448, in **init**      raise SSHException(
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to
> sftp.site.com: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because
> the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
> or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond  Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version
> 15.0.4312.2 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  14:42:00  Error: 2023-07-31 14:42:43.27
>
> Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Execute Process Task Execute Process Task
> Description: In Executing "
> C:\Users\tt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe" "
> E:/file//import_file*.py " at "E:\tt\file\data", The process exit
> code was "1" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The
> package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  14:42:00
> Finished: 14:42:43  Elapsed:  42.828 seconds.  The package execution
> failed.  The step failed.

and below is my code

```
from msilib.schema import Directory
import pysftp
import os
import glob
import fnmatch
from datetime import date, timedelta

#assuming that I have a connection to the SFTP server
 
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts.hostkeys = None

myHostname = 'sftp.mm.com'
myUsername = 'name'
myPassword = '**'

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection Success")
    remotefilepath='/data.zip/'
    localfilepath= r'E:\\data.zip'
    sftp.get(remotefilepath,localfilepath)
    print("File transfer Success")
```

Comment: The error says your SSH server didn't respond.

Comment: i can login to the sftp  server using winscup suessfully